# Applet not working properly on mozilla firefox

Tags: java, url, firefox, applet, appletviewer

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.AccessControlException;

public class TimePass extends Applet
{
    @Override
    public void start()
    {    
        try
        {
            URL u = new URL("http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/WAV/Media-Convert/Media-Convert_test1_Alaw_Mono_VBR_8SS_16000Hz.wav");

            play(u);      //Play the sound at the `URL u`
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException | AccessControlException exc)
        {
            showStatus(exc.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("play", 60, 60);       //Display "play"
    }
}
```

I tried the above applet on `appletviewer` and `mozilla firefox`

On `appletviewer`, the sound at the `URL u` was played, and `"play"` was displayed on the screen.

On `Mozilla firefox`, `"play"` was displayed on the screen but no sound was played.

Why `Mozilla firefox` is not playing the sound specified by the `URL u`?

Comment: I'd use [tag:javasound] for this.  It provides more feedback than the equivalent applet methods.  I am surprised that either can play a VBR WAV (as opposed to a fixed bit rate WAV).